# Get JSON string from angular 2 function to your c# controller in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core

I have a angular function that is executed when a button is clicked. It should send a JSON string to my c# controller. This is my angular function

```
    OnClickMe(event:any) {
    let a: boolean = true;
    if (this.llojivalue === "E Pa Siguruar") {
        a = false;
    }

    this.input = {
        Llojivalue: a,
        Monedhavalue: this.monedhaval,
        shumaval: this.shumaval,
        kohaval: this.kohaval

    }


    let b: string = JSON.stringify(this.input);

    b=JSON.parse(b);


    //console.log(b);
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "/api/Home/GetFunction", b).subscribe();



    }
```

When I write console it prints the JSON string. The code for the C# controller is like this.

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
    String str;


    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();

    }


    [HttpGet("action")]
    public void GetFunction([FromBody] string body)
    {
        str = body;
    }
```

I want the JSON string to map to my GetFunction. I am a beginner to Angular and 
ASP.NET CORE technology so it would be very helpful.

Comment: Not able to verify this, but try passing `"=" + this.input` as the body.

Comment: Passing data in the body of a GET request isn't really a best practice so I would remove the `[FromBody]` attribute and pass the string into the query string (which is what I suspect happens in the angular code). Or alternatively, make it a POST but then use a class that is compatible with the input data.

Comment: Your route is /api/Home/action and not /api/Home/GetFunction. You named it this ways by using this [HttpGet("action")] attribute.